# req.file() isn't able to fetch multiple files

Tags: html, sails.js

My html code is

```
<form action="/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="photos" id="photos" accept='image/*' multiple>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload_my_photos" disabled>
</form>
```

In sails I am using

```
uploadFiles = req.file("photos");
```

This is only fetching just single file.

Edit : I would also like to save the individual files. Below is the code I  am using but no files are getting uploaded:

```
  req.file('photos').upload(function (err, uploadedPhotos) {
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);
      async.eachSeries(uploadedPhotos, 
        function (uploadedFile, callback) {
          sails.log("upload file size and name is " + uploadedFile.size + " " + uploadedFile.filename);

          req.file(uploadedFile).upload({
            dirname: "path/to/directory",
            // saveAs: function (file, cb) { cb(null, file.filename); }
          },
          function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
              if (err) return res.serverError(err);

              if (files.length === 0) {
                return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
              }
              sails.log("files uploaded");
          });
        }, function (err) {
          // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            return res.status(200).send({ success: false, message: "failed to upload" });
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Stundji will you please look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Sails req.file() is representing an incoming multipart file upload from the specified field.**

You need to subscribe to the request with a callback in which the uploaded files will be passed as an second argument:

```
req.file('photos').upload(function (err, uploadedPhotos){
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);
  return res.json({
    message: uploadedPhotos.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
    files: uploadedPhotos
  });
});
```